# SSIS issue with data being loaded from excel file

Tags: ssis

We are getting the below errors when the SSIS package is deployed and executed.
the SSIS package contains Excel as a source.

> Data Flow Task:Error: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel
>   Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed.
>
> Package:Error: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
>   is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the
>   package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult:
>   0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered"

Comment: what type of Excel XLS or XLSX? Does the source have to be Excel? Could you get CSV instead? It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I think this has already been asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095410/ssis-package-fails-with-error-if-64-bit-driver-not-installed-run-in-32-bit-mod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS package fails with error "If 64-bit driver not installed, run in 32-bit mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095410/ssis-package-fails-with-error-if-64-bit-driver-not-installed-run-in-32-bit-mod)