# How can I make my SSIS job compatible with both XLS and XLSX files?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, oledb

I have created an `SSIS` package (using Data Tools on Windows Server 2012) which pulls data from Excel files and load them into a SQL Table. It works fine in the development environment (Data Tools) and also as a SQL job. To Note: Microsoft Office is NOT installed on the Windows Server machine. However, it does have `Access Database Engine 2010` installed.

The only hiccup is that my Excel files need to be in `xls` format (32-bit, I guess). However, I am now faced with a scenario where the Excel files will be in the `XLSX` format. So, I need to make my SSIS job compatible with these files.

I have done some research on the issue and came up with the following blogs and webpages:

1. [SSIS package fails with error “If 64-bit driver not installed, run in 32-bit mode”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095410/ssis-package-fails-with-error-if-64-bit-driver-not-installed-run-in-32-bit-mod)
2. [How to install 64-bit Microsoft Database Drivers alongside 32-bit Microsoft Office](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html)
3. [Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028775/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-is-not-registered)

However, I am still confused on how to proceed further regarding my problem.

To simplify, is the solution as follows:

1. Uninstall `Access Database Engine 2010` on Windows Server
2. Install `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe` (which is the 64-bit version of Access Database Engine)

Or are there more to it? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: The priority right now for me is to make the SSIS job work with XLSX files (the perfect scenario would be that it works with both Excel file versions)

Comment: Test, then have a loop to select either XLS or XLSX.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate please? It's not a question of selecting either/or...I need it to work with xlsx files.

Comment: Are you saying it needs to work with both files? or are you saying you built it for cls but instead you need it to work with xlsx?

Comment: `.xls` and `.xlsx` files are completely different file formats and so need different "loaders" to handle them. `.xls` files are (mostly) described by Microsoft's [Compound File Binary File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cfb/53989ce4-7b05-4f8d-829b-d08d6148375b). A description of `.xlsx` is included in [ECMA-376 Office Open XML formats](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/). You will need separate data flows and switch between them based on the file extension.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks. Any idea which component I will need in the Data Flow Task? Right now, I am using the "Excel" component as my Data Source.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I need it to work with xlsx. If need be, create a new package. Right now, when I point my Data Source (in the Dat Flow) to an Excel (xlsx) file, I have the following error: 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: The first thing you need to know is that SSDT is a 32 bit application so needs the 32 bit version installed for this to work. That may or may not be your problem. I suggest you create a new package and follow this step by step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15 The second thing you should know is that excel is about the worst data import/interchange format and you should avoid it if you possibly can

Comment: Can you write vb or c# code in a script component? In which case the microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 oledb driver will read both .xls and .xlsx files. I do it all the time. If you can I can post a code example.

Comment: @Ciarán Thanks. I would highly appreciate if you could post a code example. VB would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't manage to get around to posting the code. It's been crazy busy. Howwever, I did answer this on another question...

[Best /Fastest way to read an Excel Sheet into a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261655/best-fastest-way-to-read-an-excel-sheet-into-a-datatable/14262618)